# Assignment a function to an element in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript, and I want to assign the function `fSubmit` to my button.  Am I doing it correctly?

My code is below:

```
//Button
var btn1= document.createElement("BUTTON");      
var t1 = document.createTextNode(questions[0].A);   
btn1.appendChild(t1);
document.body.appendChild(btn1);
btn1.id='optionA';
btn1.onclick='fSubmit()';  
//End of Button

//My Function
var score=0;
function fSubmit(){
var correctanswer=btn1
if(correctanswer.checked==true){
score++;
alert("Answer is correct"+"Your Score is now"+ score++)}
else{
alert("Answer is wrong"+"Your Score is now"+score)}
}
```

Comment: Change `btn1.onclick = 'fSubmit()'; ` to `btn1.onclick = fSubmit;` Incidentally, your function isn't closed, you're missing a `}` (which is why you should always indent properly, it makes that kind of thing obvious).

Comment: Please read this carefully: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: @Eraden that link has some pretty bad examples :?

Comment: @Eraden No, he should not read that. Both because `onclick=` is very bad practice, and that `w3schools` is very bad practice.

Comment: I agree, but he is new. Event driven programming can confuse him and it's better to him to know simple way. With time he read about what is best practice and why he should not use `onclick`, `onsubmit`, etc. Please do not expect new guy be best programmer in the world. He even don't know how to attach function!

Comment: @Eraden: Better point him to http://quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html

Answer (score 0):

For starters, your button can be simplified!

```
var btn1 = document.createElement('button');
btn1.textContent = questions[0].A
btn1.id = 'optionA'

document.body.appendChild(btn1);
```

As for adding event listeners:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', fSubmit);
```

Note that I pass the function name, not in a string, and not calling with with (). `addEventListener` will call the function when the button is pressed.

Comment: Thank you ! it works but is there any way that i can proceed to the next question using a button as im doing a quiz app over here